# Using Azure Bot Bearer Token to make a GET request to external API

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, azure-bot-service, azure-authentication

I have an Azure Bot setup that authenticates the user using oAuth2. From this, I obtain an access token. I also have a web application that uses oAuth2 authentication and the same active directory as the Azure Bot. With this access token serving as bearer token, I would like to make a POST and GET request to my web application from the Azure Bot.

I've tried the following but it appears that my requests are not authenticating as I am not receiving the desired result.

```
 RestClient client = new RestClient(BaseURL);
                    RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/dashboard/GetUserName", Method.GET);
                    request.AddParameter("Authorization",
                    string.Format("Bearer " + tokenResponse.Token),
                                ParameterType.HttpHeader);
                    var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Am I misunderstanding the purpose or function of bearer tokens?

Comment: Hi vfirma, may I know what response message did you get from the request ? 401 or 403 ? Or any other error message ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. 

This is what was returned to me:

<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sign in to your account</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      .......

It's essentially asking me to authenticate despite including the bearer token in my header. The returned code is 200

Comment: You mean the request from Azure Bot to web application response 200 ? or you get the access token response 200 ?

Comment: I'm getting the access token without any issues. However, the GET request that I posted in the opening question returns  <!DOCTYPE html> <html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en"> <head> <title>Sign in to your account</title> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> ....... when using the access token as a bearer token. I'm not sure if there's just something wrong with my call or if the Azure Bot is just unable to call my Web Application's api despite authorization. The fact that I'm prompted to sign in despite the bearer token tells me that my GET request is probably wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my understanding, you just obtain the access token from Azure Bot, but you want to request from Azure Bot to another web application. So you need to get another access token from the web application and use this access token as bearer token.

The other way, you do not need to ask for another access token. You can refresh the token by referring to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token), **but you need to change the "scope" property, change it from the scope of Azure Bot to the scope from the web application.**

**Update:**

For your requirements, you need to use OAuth 2.0 on-behalf-of flow, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).
[image]

In the flow image above, the "Web API A" represents your Azure Bot and the "Web API B" represents your web application. You need to get the first access token for Web API A and then get the second token for Web API B. After that you can request Web API B.

Comment: My Azure bot prompts the user to login using oAuth2. This gives me an access token. Am I not able to use the same access token to access the contents of my Web Application despite the two sharing the same active directory?

Comment: @vfirma Yes, you can't use the same access token to request the web application. But according to your description, maybe I misunderstood your requirements, I will edit my answer later.

Comment: According to this documentation, it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0. I could be wrong though.

What I essentially want to do is use this access token as a bearer token when making my GET and POST requests. Though I'm not sure why the code in the opening question isn't working

Comment: Hi @vfirma, I have updated my answer. If you want to request from your Azure Bot to web application, please refer to the answer under "Update". If you just want to request the web application from your application after request Azure Bot, please refer to the previous solution.

Comment: Do you know what token the Azure Bot is returning? Initially I thought it was the access token but it may be an authorization code. I tried to exchange this for an access token at my web application but no luck

Comment: Hi @vfirma, according to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634006/what-is-the-token-returned-by-the-azure-bot) which you created, it seems you need to use the first solution I provided above. You can get the access token by refresh_token, the solution provided by Allen in that post is the right answer for your question.