# What is the token returned by the Azure Bot?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-bot-service, azure-authentication

I followed this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) to setup authentication for my Azure Bot. After a successful login, it returns a token for me. I believe that this is an authorization token to access the Microsoft Graph API. If I wanted to use this same token to exchange for an access token to another web application, is that possible? And how would I be able to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possilbe.

You should be able to get a refresh_token after the authorization is finished.

Use this refresh_token to exchange another access_token with the `scope` of another web application. Like this:

[image]

Then we can get an access_token for another scope:

[image]

You can see that the scope has changed from `https://graph.microsoft.com` to `api://{id}/user.write` which is another web API.

---

**UPDATE:**

Maybe I have a misunderstanding because I see you want to exchange a new access token.

If you just want to access your own web api from Bot application and don't need to call Microsoft Graph API, just modify the **Resource URL** (Azure AD v1) or **Scopes** (Azure AD v2). It's unnecessary to exchange a new access token.

For [Azure AD v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#azure-ad-v1), you should set Resource URL as: `api://{api id}`.

For [Azure AD v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#azure-ad-v2), set Scopes as: `api://{api id}/.default`.

Please note that `api://{api id}` is your web api.

Comment: Hello @Allen Wu, thank you so much for your response. What you responded is exactly what I wanted to do. One question I have pertains to the token. Using this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) I was able to setup authentication by conversation through the bot. The token I obtain from this is of the form "eyJ0......". Is this an authentication code or an access token?

Comment: @vfirma It's access token. You don't need to use authentication code in my steps above. And you need to get the refresh_token rather than access_token. Then use the refresh_token to exchange the new access_token.

Comment: Can this not be done using that access token value? It appears my bot is only giving me that token, or I might be missing the refresh_token somewhere

Comment: After trying this, I received 

{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: 4f9be336-22bc-4ee5-89a9-c342b6ba8900\r\nCorrelation ID: 9f4716e4-136b-437d-864e-bde2c1320306\r\nTimestamp: 2020-01-08 06:43:00Z",
    "error_codes": [
        9002313
    ]

This is using the client_id and client_secret of the Azure Bot.

Comment: @vfirma Per my understanding, it seems that you don't want to call Microsoft Graph API. What you want is to call your own web api. Is that right? You call Microsoft Graph API just because the official sample is for accessing Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Allen, that is correct. I have a web api that uses oauth2 to grant access. I thought that the access token obtained from the bot could be used